# How Blog software such as Windows Live Writer access Blogs

Tags: web-services, json, blogs, telligent

I am wondering How a blog software such as Windows Live writer reads/updates so many blogs such as Telligent, Wordpress, Blogger blogs.

Is there a commom web services standard exposed by these blog providers?

I have a telligent blog hosted on blogs.msdn.com and looking to access it contents in my custom web program. Any idea how can I do that ?

Comment: They appear to have a REST API - http://telligent.com/community/developers/w/wiki/platform-api-documentation.aspx . WordPress has a PHP API, not sure if they have a REST one now.

Comment: Thats proprietary .. thats my questions is.. Does WLW has seperate implementation for each of its provider ?

Comment: Going by this Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Live_Writer , under Integration it looks like there is a WLW API that blogs can use to link to it. Regarding WP and other blog integration, my guess is they would have a separate interface for each platform since there is no unified API for writing to blogs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Live Writer uses the [MetaWeblog API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MetaWeblog) to access blog and post information. Telligent's endpoint can be found at /blogs/metablog.ashx. Many other blog platforms use the same standard (although some such as Wordpress add additional features). The [XML-RPC](http://www.xml-rpc.net/) can be helpful when calling Meta Weblog services.